# is there any way to define data type on json data in postgreSQL

Tags: typescript, postgresql

I have typescript interface with one property is float and other is string. I can insert json data direcly into table but I am wondering is there any way to define data types in the json data.

```
interface students{
    percentage: Number;
    name: string;
}
```

Comment: No, JSON doesn't really have a notion of data types nor does it enforce them. If you want that, use a properly normalized data model where your JSON keys are mapped to table column with the correct data type.

Comment: You could create a domain type, but then really there's no reason to use JSON underneath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can make a check constraint that does that:

```
create table student (
    data jsonb check (
        coalesce(jsonb_typeof(data->'name'),'') = 'string' and 
        coalesce(jsonb_typeof(data->'percentage'),'')='number'
    )
);
```

But why not store the data as columns which are inherently typed instead?